# Automate alignment of columns in CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I often work with CSV files, that other people will work with in a text editor.  I want to have nice alignment of columns, e.g.:

```
Height,  Age, Whatever
11,      12,  13
```

For large files, this is tedious to maintain manually...what's the best way to do this automatically?

I have Windows and Linux available, with standard tools like MS Office (Excel).

So, for my own use, I can use Excel or other tools to display the file nicely. However I want something which will allow others to see the file properly in a text editor, without using special tools.

Comment: How are you giving bonus points without a bounty on the question? BTW, what have you attempted so far?

Comment: You want to csv to have alignment when viewed as a text file, not in excel? Try tab delimited?

Comment: Bonus points was a figure of speach :-).  I don't have enough rep to offer a bounty, sorry!

Comment: The files are CSV, not tab delimited.  Can't change all the CSV files in the world even if I wanted to!

Comment: What is wrong with importing the CSV into Excel? Does this not align it for you? Or are you trying to achieve this for use in text editors?

Comment: I am not exactly giving you a solution, but how about using "Format Painter" in excel and do alignment of cells or columns?. Open the .csv file in an Excel and Format a cell as per your requirement. Now, use "Format Painter" to copy a applied format in a cell and apply it across all cells or columns.

Comment: For my own use, I can use Excel or other tools to display the file nicely.  However I want something which will allow others to see the file properly in a text editor, without using special tools.

Comment: You will have to either find a text editor that supports what you ask for - or write (create) your own. Note that Excel is buggy in the regard that a single ALT+ENTER in ONE cell (=CSV field) breaks the re-import due to the linefeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can export it as a PRN file, but you can not keep the comma as a delimiter. The delimiter will be the spaces.

[image]